# Is it possible to call a non-specialized template function although a specialized function exists?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

If I have a template function with specializations, is it possible to explicitly call the non-specialized template?

```
template<class IntegerType>
inline IntegerType bitCount(IntegerType bitset)
{
  puts("general");
  return 0;
}

template<>
inline std::uint64_t bitCount(std::uint64_t bitset)
{
  puts("specialized");
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  std::uint64_t x = 1<<5;
  std::cout << bitCount(x) << '\n'; //specialized
  std::cout << bitCount<std::uint64_t>(x) << '\n'; //specialized
  return 0;
}
```

My use case is that I want to write unit tests to ensure that the generic function and its specializations yield the same results.

Comment: FWIW, prefer overloads to specializations.  Function template specializations are still not functions and as such do not participate in overload resolution.

Comment: But then how is the overload resolution if I have functions and function templates with the same name?

Comment: I have read several times that overloads are "better" than specializations. But why? Do you have any source which explains why it is better?

Comment: Found something useful: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the specialisation *is* `bitCount<std::uint64_t>`.

If you have a `#define` for your testing, you could instead overload `bitCount` during the tests

```
template<class IntegerType>
inline IntegerType bitCount(IntegerType bitset)
{
  puts("general");
  return 0;
}

#ifndef(TEST_BITCOUNT)
template<>
#endif
inline std::uint64_t bitCount(std::uint64_t bitset)
{
  puts("specialized");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any good reason not to make the specialized template a non-template function? In your code, is there a disadvantage if I always definie TEST_BITCOUNT?

Comment: @Fabian Overloads behave differently to specialisations, especially when other overloads are present. It's probably better to overload than to specialise

Comment: In your answer, shouldn't it be #ifndef? In test mode, I need the normal function, hence there must not be template<>. In normal mode, the function may be a specialized template.